# Duplication of Magento transactions

Tags: magento

We have large number of orders with duplicate payments.

I have checked the Magento var/report access logs and error logs. I was unable to find any fatel errors. But could be able to find database deadlocks on magento reports.

Is there any kind of relationship between this deadlocks and duplicate payments?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?